# at-command: Scheduling and process priority

Tags: linux, batch, at

I have about 10 "at" jobs. There are cases where there is a conflict of resources and I am trying to find a neat way to schedule this. Say, job#5 may want to start before the job#4 ends. Each job has a priority/weight. If job#5 has higher priority, it can kill job#1 and start. How do I incorporate such a method of scheduling?

Thanks.

Comment: You are clearly pushing the `at` subsystem too far from what it was designed for. You probably need to redesign things and understand why you have 10 jobs that seem separate, because written as 10 jobs, but at the same time having dependencies between them. You could have a look at newer solutions like `systemd.timer` but even that may not have the features you need.

Comment: Thanks. Right now I solved it by creating and deleting a file FLAG.txt with certain parameters. Each job checks for the existence of that file and the parameters. The subsequent at job will proceed or exit based on those parameters. Works OK, but hoped to find a better way.